# Disable auto rewind VIDEO in HTML on ended

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video

I'm integrating some local html slider to custom app. My html+js works correctly in default browsers, but when i launch in custom app - video player looks like another and when video ends, it reset timeline to beginning.

It should be stopped on the end of the timeline, cause js of carousel looks for 'ended' and then play next slide.

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="slider">
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme video-slider-1">
          <img src="1.jpg" id="photocss" /> <!-- Фото -->
          <video   muted  autoPlay controls  id="videocss"  ">
            <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <!-- Видео 1 -->
          </video>
          <img src="2.jpg" id="photocss" /> <!-- Фото -->
          <img src="3.jpg" id="photocss" /> <!-- Фото -->
          <video muted  autoPlay controls id="videocss"">
            <source src="2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <!-- Видео 2 -->
          </video>
          <img src="4.jpg" id="photocss" />
          <img src="5.jpg" id="photocss" /> <!-- Фото -->
          <video muted  autoPlay controls id="videocss"">
            <source src="3.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <!-- Видео 2 -->
          </video>
          <img src="6.jpg" id="photocss" /> <!-- Фото -->
         
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS which chek when 'ended' then play. On 0(zero) it stop

```
 onTranslated: function() {
    if ($(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).length) {
      $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element)[0].play();
      owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
      $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).on('ended', function() {
        owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay')
      });
    }
  }
});
```

[image - current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRVDG.jpg):
[image]

[image - expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkpa6.jpg): 
[image]

Comment: There are some errors in your HTML markup - your `photocss` id is not unique (the same goes for `videocss`). Also, there's an extra quote in your `<video muted  autoPlay controls id="videocss"">` elements.

Comment: Please see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/76bxu9f5/). Are you initializing your Owl carousel differently? Your JS code is incomplete, so the fiddle I provided may be quite off from what you really have. Does your problem persist in different browsers and / or devices?

Comment: it is not full text of js. it also have code like in your example. the specific problem is with timeline in normal browsers and that, in which my code is integrated. Below are screenshots via links how it works

Answer (score 0):

You could try pausing the video on its playback ending.

Does something like this help you in anyway? 
It is **untested** code but the logic is there to test n your own code ...

```
onTranslated: function() {
    if ($(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).length) 
    {
      //# temp variable to avoid long typing when re-using...
      var vid_current = $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element)[0];
      
      vid_current.play();
      owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
      
      vid_current.on('ended',   function() 
                        {
                            vid_current.pause();
                            owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay')
                        }
      );
    }
  }
});
```